# How to remove redundant info from Gerrit cherry-pick auto appended git commit message?

Tags: git, gerrit

My Gerrit projects use “Cherry Pick” as “Submit Type”. I found when a commit is submitted, some information will be appended to the commit message automatically. For example:

```
commit 96570819f3dfdea982aaeac8d6274f06ce7faecf
Author: zhiping.lzp <zhiping.lzp@somecompany-inc.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 14 13:28:49 2015 +0800

    BugID:5910789: fix incorrect stackId/taskId.

    Change-Id: I0e25267b2f45b60394c0615207848ed83ba95291
    Reviewed-on: http://gerrit3.somecompany-inc.com:8080/89729
    Reviewed-by: hongbo.mhb <hongbo.mhb@somecompany-inc.com>
    Reviewed-by: qiangbo.qb <qiangbo.qb@somecompany-inc.com>
```

And, I also read from gerrit manual:

When cherry picking a change, Gerrit automatically appends onto the end of the commit message a short summary of the change’s approvals, and a URL link back to the change on the web.

What I want to do is to keep “Change_id” and “Reviewed-on” lines and get rid of “Reviewed-by” lines since the information is not necessary to be shown there (we could use reviewnotes plugin to implement when needed) and it makes repository getting bigger.

How could I do this?